# ReactJS use a webcomponent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript

I could find a lot of documentation to use a WebComponent using JSX in React. Well it's pretty straight forward...

But how to use a webcomponent in JavaScript with ReactJS ??

```
render: function(){
  React.DOM.div {}, 
    MyWebComponent {}, "hello"
```

Where 'MyWebComponent' is the component that I want to work with.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript react.createElement takes an element or componant as the first argument, styles as the second argument, children as the third agrument.

```
            import customComponent from 'my-custom-component';
            var child = React.createElement(customComponent, null, 'Text Content');
            var Element = React.createElement('div', { className: 'my-class' }, child);


            render: function(){ 
                {Element}
            }
```

or you can do this

```
...
 import customComponent from 'my-custom-component';
...

render: function(){ 
       {React.createElement('div', { className: 'my-class' },customComponent );}
}
```

Comment: yes but let say that I have `<webcomponent>`. Now what is webcomponent ? 

This doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/g4y4kgw7/

Comment: @Kursion The fiddle you posted isn't javascript, it's just one big syntax error. When you say `webcomponent`, do you mean a React component that you made, or a HTML5 working draft custom element with shadow DOM and all the bells and whistles that go with it?

Comment: When I say `webcomponent` I mean any valid child element. It could be any valid element that can be rendered. any valid element that can be rendered `var child = React.createElement(CustomComponent, null, null);`

Comment: @AKADER Yeah, I got your back. My question was directed at OP.

Comment: Thanks I misunderstood.

Comment: I was talking about an HTML5 component. Well I found out how to do it using a mix of `React.createElement` and `document.createElement`. Thanks a lot for your time ! You helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated [in the official react site](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/webcomponents.html) you should be able to use web components with react

```
render: function(){
  return <div><MyWebComponent>hello</MyWebComponent></div>;
}
```

here is the same example in pure js

```
render: function render() {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    React.createElement(
      MyWebComponent,
      null,
      "hello"
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: this is JSX. As I mentionned, I'm using pure JavaScript and can't use JSX on my environnement.

Comment: React.createElement is the way to go then https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=a%20%3D%20%7B%0Arender%3A%20function()%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3E%3CMyWebComponent%3Ehello%3C%2FMyWebComponent%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%7D